# How to display digit always with two decimal places - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display digit always with two decimal values. 
I can display values with two decimal values.

```
$scope.value1 = 10000;
$scope.value2 = 12444.44443;
```

In controller I used

```
$scope.value1 = $scope.value1.toFixed(2);
$scope.value2 = $scope.value2.toFixed(2);
```

Then in HTML, I can display as "**`10000.00`**" "**`12444.44`**". But its changing my model value also. I don't want to change the value. I want to display value only as "**`1000.00`**" "**`12444.44`**".

Even I tried as

```
{{value1 | setDecimal : 2 }}
{{value2 | setDecimal : 2 }}
```

It displays as

```
10000
12444.44
```

This `setDecimal` changes only my decimal value.

I want to display like `setDecimal` but need to display 10000 also as 10000.00.

Comment: `{{value1 | number: 2}}` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number . not sure where you saw the "setDecimal" pipe, but the "number" pipe should be enough here.

Comment: @Md.AtiqulIslam yes it will: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/13963/

Comment: Besides, avoid using `toFixed` or whatever unless it's strictly needed: angularjs is heavy already, so avoid adding stuff that exists already. The `number` pipe was invented for such a scope, so just use it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `number` filter as a pipe in your template to achieve this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.value1 = 10000;
  $scope.value2 = 12444.44443;
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>{{ value1 | number: 2 }}</p>    
    <p>{{ value2 | number: 2 }}</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: before 3 min @brioseje answered in comment

Comment: It should be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @MaximShoustin that's fine. Yadejo: Please it would be worth to mention that it is a pipe in this case. Also, provide a fiddle to make the answer more complete.

Comment: @briosheje I took your comment into account, hope you can agree with this answer.

Comment: @yadejo yep, that's a complete answer :)

Comment: I have should not display "`,`". I have tried {{value1 | number : 2}}. This also showing "`,`" value as currency.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the code output. And I think this [Documents](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) is really helpful

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app> {{12342 | number: 2}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value.toFixed(2)
```

should give what you need

Answer (score 0):

use toFixed(2) method for fixing it to two

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FQTqk/7/)

```
parseFloat(Math.round(num3 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```